# get console output

Tags: python-3.x

how can i receive the console output of any python file (errors, everything printed using the print() command)?

example:
main.py starts test.py and gets its output

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.stderr from the sys module. print() uses sys.stdout by default.

```
import sys

# Print to standard output stream
print("Normal output...")

# Print to standard error stream
print("Error output...", file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if this will help but im sure it will give you an idea. 
in vb.net or c#.net we capture console stream using the process StandardOutput like this:

```
Dim p as Process = Process.Start("cmd")
p.WaitForExit(Integer.MaxValue)
dim output as String = p.StandardOutput
```